# isset not returning a value (or at least the right one)

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to PHP and have hit a brick wall. When a user logs in on my site, a session ID is generated and stored in a database, along with the expiration time, user's email and IP. The session ID is also stored in the user's cookies, and expires after 30 minutes of inactivity. When a page is loaded, part of the navbar is determined by whether or not they are logged in, which is determined by whether or not part a cookie is set. My code is shown below.

### Change the navbar

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE['sessionID'])) {
   echo "<li><a href=\"login\"><i class=\"material-icons\">account_circle</i></a></li>";
} else {
   echo "<li><a href=\"login\">Login</a></li>\n";
}

?>
```

### Log a user in

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `email`='$email'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (password_verify($password, mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)['password'])) {
  $sessionID = uniqid('id_', true);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO sessions (`email`, `ID`, `expiration`, `ip`) VALUES ('$email', '$sessionID', '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+30 minutes")) . "', '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "')";

  setcookie("sessionID", $sessionID);
  $_COOKIE['sessionID'] = $sessionID;

  mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  header("Location: https://[censor]/");
  exit();
} else {
  header("Location: https://[censor]/login?success=false");
  exit();

}
```

I know a user has been logged in, at least to a degree, because `sessionID` shows up on the database and my cookies.

## Update

I started using PHP sessions, and after getting them to work once, they appear to have stopped working. My new code is below.

### Logging a user in

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `email`='$email'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (password_verify($password, mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)['password'])) {

  $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

  header("Location: https://[censor]/");

  echo $_SESSION['email'];

  exit();
} else {
  header("Location: https://[censor]/login?success=false");
  exit();

}
```

And no, I did not forget to start a session, it is started at the very beginning of the file.

### Example

```
<?php

  if (isset($_SESSION['email']))
    echo "<li><a href=\"login\"><i class=\"material-icons\">account_circle</i></a></li>";
  else
    echo "<li><a href=\"login\">Login</a></li>\n";

?>
```

Comment: you have to say `session_start()` at every script before using any session vars. [Here's the Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: @Jeff It looks like he's rolling his own session system. So he doesn't have to

Comment: @Machavity oops, have been too quickly reading then.. just saw "session" without starting it.

Comment: @Jeff It does raise a good question. Why do it this way? PHP sessions are much cleaner and easier to implement

Comment: @Machavity I've never seen anything about PHP sessions until now. What I mainly don't understand is why the cookie is showing up through Chrome's settings but still not considered "set".

Comment: @ZonalYewHD that is strange, indeed. Could it be, that login page is http, the rest https? Or maybe another subdomain? Anyway, have a look at php sessions. They do all that you are doing here out of the box.

Comment: I should also note that `$_COOKIE['sessionID'] = $sessionID;` is unnecessary. That's what `setcookie` is for

Comment: @Machavity I saw another post that mentioned that the `$_COOKIE` array wasn't updated until a second page load, and wanted to verify that wasn't the issue.

Comment: @Jeff I tried that, and I have a question. Is a session unique for every visitor to the site, or sitewide?

Comment: @ZonalYewHD You cannot use `setcookie` and call/set the cookie in the same page run (it's a header thing)

Comment: @Machavity Gotcha. Well if php sessions work, I won't need my method anymore anyway.

Comment: @Jeff I got php sessions to work once, but they haven't since... I updated my code above with my new issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same isset error. I don't know exactly why this is not working but I solved the problem with this:

```
$val = true;
if(isset($_COOKIE['sessionID'])){
   $val = false;
}

if($val == true){
//action 1
}
else{
//action 2
}
```

I think that should work in your case as well. Or is isset generally not working, if you use it without the else?

Answer (score 0):

it will be better if you use **SESSIONS** for login; here is a sample code.Here i get the login information from the login form, assign it to respective variables and compare with what is in my **DATABASE**.`

```
<?php session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$username=validate_data($username);

$query="SELECT * FROM users;";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
comfirm_query($result);

  //fetching login info
while ($user=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   //verifying info
    if($user['username']==$username){
      if (password_verify($password,$user['password'])) {
        /*if success set the session super global variable with indexes  
       user_id and username with the values gotten from the database*/
        $_SESSION['user_id']=$user['id'];
        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
        redirect_to("admin.php");
       }
       else{
        $_SESSION['login_message']="username or password not correct";
       }
    }
    else
        $_SESSION['login_message']="username or password not correct";
  }

}
?>
```

Now to verify **login** on any page which requires a user to be **logged on**

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    header("location:login.php");
    exit;
 }else{
 /*continue executing code on page; the else is not really 
 necessary as if the variable is not set, the user 
 will be redirected; but if it #is set , 
 the just skip (permit me to use this word) 
 the if and get on with the code*/
  }
?>
```